# Angular cli assets folder structure

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I prepared angular cli config for some reasons I need to build two applications inside one repository. All applications have separated assets inside project "/app/first-app/assets". The problem: after building dist assets have a strange structure.

**dist/first-app/** here I have all scripts

Now assets part:

**dist/first-app/**/app/first-app/assets/i18n etc

I want to keep structure like this:

**dist/first-app/**assets/i18n

Is it possible to configure it in cli?

```
"apps": [
{
  "name": "first-app",
  "outDir": "dist/first-app",
  "assets": [
    "./src/app/first-app/assets",   --this part is separated for each app
    "favicon.ico"
  ]
} ... more apps
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your whole first-app is in `src/app/first-app`, setting it as just "assets" should work (Angular 5.2.x, Angular Cli 1.7.x). Cli should look for it under "root" and copy it under "outDir".

```
"root": "src/app/first-app",
"outDir": "dist/first-app",
"assets": ["assets", ...
```

But if your directory strucure is just too unconventional, cli may not be able to do what you want. In that case, gulp, grunt or just a simple nodejs script to the rescue. Add one to your `npm build` script that copies the assets where you want them.